# Where is my logout button

Tags: phpmyadmin

I just setup phpmyadmin version 4.4.

I need to be able to logout, but I can't find the button.

How do I add it back?

I found articles for changing config to cookies in the .ini file, but it's not even there anymore.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an .ini file but config.inc.php.

Answer (score 0):

Type `/logout` after `host` part of `URL` and press enter. Like:

```
https://db.example.com:2083/logout
```